# Wordpress $curauth conditional statement on author.php

Tags: php, wordpress, author

I am trying to display twitter & facebook links on the author.php page only if these have been added to the profile in the backend.

I can display the Twitter profile using $curauthor with this code:
twitter); ?>">Twitter

How do I put this in to a conditional statement so it only shows this URL if the details have been added for that user?

Thanks!

Comment: Quite easily, show us what you've  tried first

Comment: how you are adding those links to user profile?, If you are storing it in meta, just fetch the same value and check if is not null, display links else not

Comment: I'm using Custom About Author plugin to extend the profile in the backend. I've used the following code to try and pull this in to the author.php but it keeps returning the 'else' statement even when the twitter address is in the profile.

Comment: My code is <?php if ( get_the_author_meta(CAA_Author::twitter) ) { ?>
<p><a class="meta-website" href="<?php echo nl2br ($curauth->twitter); ?>">Twitter</a>    </p>
<?php }
else { ?>
<p>No Twitter Account</p>
<?php } ?>